# Create a raster layer that represents the distance from each polygon cell to the closest point in a buffer

Tags: qgis, raster, distance

Let's say I have polygons A and B (green), polygon centroids (white), buffers around these centroids (blue), and a collection of points (red). I want to create a raster layer that represents the distance from each polygon cell to the closest point (red) within the polygon buffer (blue). For the raster of A, the distance should be to the closest point (red) in A's buffer region. I think I need to first rasterize the shapefile containing A and B, but I'm getting an error.

I created a [basic example](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vh612bh9a85uvq4/AADr1uI-d70Rw0iLxH5L2LZla?dl=0) of this setup in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: with grass plugin you may use r.grow.distance

Comment: What did you try? I downloaded your example folder and shapefiles are located in Africa (Uganda), with EPSG:4326, and they are representing a very huge area (I guess it is a fictional example) . I could rasterize without any issues by using a resolution of 0.001 degrees. You got an error because probably high values were used for resolution with QGIS rasterize tool (default values, in meters, are 100).